# Using BIND and DHCP together

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

I am currently using a home router as both DHCP server and DNS resolver like most home users.

This is fine when a device wants to contact the outside world because the DNS works.  When I want an internal device to talk to another, I end up manually managing IP addresses and host files which is a real pain.

My thought is to install DNS and DHCP onto my Ubuntu server; this seems simple.  What I cannot see is where the two are connected.  If "henrys-iphone" is given an IP address from DHCP, how does the DNS server know that henrys-iphone.home is mapped to 192.168.1.X?

Is this automatic, or do I set up up manually?  I have spent a lot of time looking on Google, but there doesn't seem to be anything there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my system, I would have done "henrys-iphone" DHCP lease and address assignment based on MAC address. Then I know that "henrys-iphone" will always be at 92.168.1.X. And that same information is in my bind configuration for DNS forward and reverse lookups. There is a way to automatically get bind to know what IP "henrys-iphone" got, but I do not how. If what I do is what you are looking for, I'll write and answer, but it will take awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure

- The DHCP server to perform Dynamic Updates (including domain name to use and server)
- The BIND server to allow updates from the DHCP server IP
- An internal Domain on your BIND DNS server

At least at a high level that is what you need. When a client gets an IP from your DHCP server, the DHCP server will update the DNS server with the A record and IP.